# Connecting to Sourceforge.net MySQL database in Netbeans

Tags: mysql, netbeans, sourceforge

I am trying to connect my MySQL database hosted on Sourceforge.net in Netbeans. But database connection test fails. I have entered database settings as described at Sourceforge.net MySQL admin panel but it does not work. Here settings described at Sourceforge:

[image]

Here what I tried in Netbeans:

[image]

Comment: if it is hosted somewhere else, you should put in a url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give yourself the access, read [this documentation](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Direct%20MySQL%20access%20over%20the%20Internet) :

> Once access has been granted via the management interface, you may connect using the MySQL server provided to your project, using one of the database accounts provided to your project.
>
> For example, after authorizing yourself for access, you may connect to the database as follows (replace USERNAME and LETTER as documented):
>
> mysql -u USERNAME -h mysql-LETTER.sourceforge.net -P 4040 -p

By the way reading the doc, the purpose of is not to be access consistantly by an application, indeed the provided access is temporary.

> Access to the Project database servers is typically firewalled. To provide this direct access over the Internet, we temporarily (4 hours at time) open a hole in our firewall to permit your traffic to the project database servers.